# Regression manhwa where the female lead is given a cooking/healing skill

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I'm trying to find the title of this regression manhwa.

The female lead died in the hands of her knight, which was ordered by his father, and male lead came back from the war with her lover. The female lead dies, but she came back to the time in which the male lead is still on war. The God/Author gave her three skills, and she chose skills in cooking and healing. She makes vitality pills and mana pills.

After coming back, she found out that her father continuously gave her a poison that makes her infertile. She agreed to adopt the male lead's niece then she also sends aids and mana pills to his husband when the king decided to betray her husband.

There was a scene on which the male side characters enter her room, which the male lead found out because he has these sensitive skills.

Also there's a scene where side characters transform into rats so they can save the female lead's brother.

She meets someone named Seven(?) and sells vitality pills and mana pills underground for her to have her own money because she's planning to divorce the male lead.

Comment: Do you remember if the new world was pure fantasy like (ie DnD like setting), or if it was more like 19th century plus magic?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.